CI/CD Pipeline Skips Deployments in Multi-Environment Setup
I am building a CI/CD pipeline with the following steps:

Check for any changes.
If changes are found, deploy.

This setup is intended for multiple environments. However, I am encountering an issue when there are more than one environment to deploy:
The deployment for the first environment from the template works as expected. However, the second environment, despite detecting changes, does not initiate the deployment and is marked as "skipped". First env always work like a charm:

Here's a simplified version of my pipeline configuration:
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

stages:
- template: templates/deploy.yml
  parameters:
    environment: Dev

- template: templates/deploy.yml
  parameters:
    environment: Uat

and deploy.yml template:
stages:
- stage: Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Plan
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job: Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}
    displayName: Plan Terraform
    pool: 'selfhosted'
    steps:

    - powershell: |
          # set it to true or false
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges;isOutput=true]true"

      displayName: Detect any Terraform changes
      name: anyTfChanges


- stage: Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Terraform Changes
  dependsOn: Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}
  variables:
     anyTfChanges: $[ stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['anyTfChanges.anyTfChanges'] ]
  condition: and(eq('true', 'true'), eq(dependencies.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.anyTfChanges.anyTfChanges'], 'true'))
 
  jobs:
    - job: Terraform_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}
      displayName: Detect Terraform Changes
      steps:
      - checkout: none
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "hello world"
        displayName: Terraform changes detected

- stage: Terraform_Apply_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Apply ${{ parameters.environment }}
  dependsOn: Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}
  jobs:
  - deployment: Apply
    environment: ${{ parameters.environmentDisplayName }}
    displayName: Apply Terraform
    pool: 'selfhosted'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
          - script: |
              Write-Host "hello world"

Could I be overlooking something in my configuration that causes the pipeline to behave this way for subsequent environments? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!
EDIT1
It only works for first stage:

And when next one has changes. For third one (prod) it does not work when middle stage doesnt have changes

Also when i have two stages, and no changes in first one i can not deploy to second stage because apply stage is skipped
EDIT2
When i commented depends on: in apply stage, it still does not work:


I would start with redefining the condiiton of stage "Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }} condition from "dependencies" to "stageDependencies" on line 24: condition: and(eq('true', 'true'), eq(stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}...

@Danielson didnt change anything, when i change condition to stageDependencies... schema it doesnt hit that stage (check changes) at all.

When designing more complex pipelines, I always try to define the stages, jobs, tasks, variables with proper suffix for better readability. Having task and varaible with the same name might be confusing in troubleshooting. Once you've got that, it is much easier to troubleshoot
Nevertheless, when you are editing the core pipeline definition (Pipelines -> Pipeline Name -> Edit), then click on 3 dots in upper right corner and click "Download Full YAML". There, you can review whole pipeline constructed with each template filled with parameters and determine, if there is issue.

Can you try removing whole 'variables' definition on lines 22 and 23 and test it?

@Danielson same issue. When i comment variables section, when i print anyTfChanges output is empty. Before i had value. Pipeline's expanded view looks ok for me. Also when first stage has deployment, everything works like a charm.

@Danielson when i delete variables, anyTfChanges var is empty. Please check my edit

@Danielson check my last edit. It still does not work when i comment depends on property in apply stage

Hi @michasaucer, Have you got a chance to test my suggestion to add condition: succeeded('Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}') for apply stage? I have shared the test results in my answer below as well. Hope it works for you. Cheers.

Hi @michasaucer, May I ask the latest status of the issue and if you have got a chance to test my suggestion to add condition: succeeded('Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}') for apply stage? The test results in my answer below showed the apply stage could be runing if Any_Tf_Changes stage succeeded and even if other previous stages were skipped or failed. Hope it works for you.

From Define conditions:

By default, a stage runs if it doesn't depend on any other stage, or
if all of the stages that it depends on have completed and
succeeded. You can customize this behavior by forcing a stage to run
even if a previous stage fails or by specifying a custom condition.

The Apply Prd stage has no conditions set and some of the previous stages were skipped, so that's why the stage was skipped:

Fixing the pipeline
The below example pipeline was used to test the dependencies between stages.
Set applyChanges value to true or false to simulate changes in each environment:
azure-pipeline.yml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      environment: 'Dev'
      applyChanges: 'true'
  
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      environment: Uat
      applyChanges: 'false'
  
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      environment: Prod
      applyChanges: 'true'

templates/deploy.yml
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: Environment
  type: string

- name: applyChanges
  displayName: Apply Changes
  type: string

- name: environmentDisplayName
  displayName: Environment Display Name
  type: string
  default: my-environment # change it to an existing environment

stages:
- stage: plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Plan ${{ parameters.environment }}
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job: plan_job # no need to have distinct job names for jobs running in different stages
    displayName: Plan Terraform ${{ parameters.environment }}
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
          # set it to true or false
          Write-Host "anyTfChanges=${{ parameters.applyChanges }}"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges;isOutput=true]${{ parameters.applyChanges }}"
      displayName: Detect any Terraform changes
      name: detectChanges


- stage: detect_changes_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Terraform Changes ${{ parameters.environment }}
  dependsOn: plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}
  # condition syntax: dependencies.STAGE_NAME.outputs['JOB_NAME.TASK_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME']
  condition: eq(dependencies.plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['plan_job.detectChanges.anyTfChanges'], 'true')
  # OR
  # previous stage succeeded and there are changes (anyTfChanges=true)
  # condition: and(succeeded('plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}'), eq(dependencies.plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['plan_job.detectChanges.anyTfChanges'], 'true'))
  variables:
    # variable syntax: stageDependencies.STAGE_NAME.JOB_NAME.outputs['TASK_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME']
    anyTfChanges: $[ stageDependencies.plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}.plan_job.outputs['detectChanges.anyTfChanges'] ]
  jobs:
    - job: detect_changes_job # no need to have distinct job names for jobs running in different stages
      displayName: Detect Changes ${{ parameters.environment }}
      steps:
      - checkout: none
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "anyTfChanges: $(anyTfChanges)"
        displayName: Terraform changes detected

- stage: apply_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Apply ${{ parameters.environment }}
  dependsOn: detect_changes_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}
  # condition syntax: dependencies.STAGE_NAME.outputs['JOB_NAME.TASK_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME']
  condition: eq(dependencies.plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['plan_job.detectChanges.anyTfChanges'], 'true')
  # OR
  # previous stage succeeded and there are changes (anyTfChanges=true)
  # condition: and(succeeded('detect_changes_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}'), eq(dependencies.plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['plan_job.detectChanges.anyTfChanges'], 'true'))
  variables:
    # variable syntax: stageDependencies.STAGE_NAME.JOB_NAME.outputs['TASK_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME']
    anyTfChanges: $[ stageDependencies.plan_stage_${{ parameters.environment }}.plan_job.outputs['detectChanges.anyTfChanges'] ]
  jobs:
  - deployment: Apply
    environment: ${{ parameters.environmentDisplayName }}
    displayName: Apply Changes ${{ parameters.environment }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - powershell: |
              Write-Host "anyTfChanges: $(anyTfChanges)"
            displayName: Apply changes

Please note that I've changed the names of the stages, jobs and tasks to make it easier to understand.
Running the pipeline:


Based on the documents Conditions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn and Define variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn, please pay attention to the YAML pipeline default behaviors:

Since there are no explicit dependencies set for stage Terraform_Apply_${{ parameters.environment }}, by default, it depends on the stage just before it in the YAML file.
Since there are no explicit conditions set for stage Terraform_Apply_${{ parameters.environment }}, it will use the default condition, which means this stage runs if all direct and indirect dependencies have succeeded, as if you specified condition: succeeded().
In addition, when you specify your own condition property for a stage / job / step, you overwrite its default condition: succeeded(). Therefore, you may consider adding the same condition in stage Terraform_Apply_${{ parameters.environment }} as that you defined for stage Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}.
Furthermore, please also make sure you take into account the state of the parent stage Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }} when writing your own conditions, since overwriting the default condition can lead to your stage running even if the build is cancelled or failed.

With those being said, if your actual expectation is to run the stage Terraform_Apply_${{ parameters.environment }} only when the stage Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }} is succeeded, you can try adding the expression eq(dependencies.Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}.result, 'Succeeded') or succeeded('Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}') for apply stage. Here is the part of stage Terraform_Apply_${{ parameters.environment }} of the YAML pipeline for your reference.
- stage: Terraform_Apply_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Apply ${{ parameters.environment }}
  condition: and(
      eq('true', 'true'),
      eq(dependencies.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.anyTfChanges.anyTfChanges'], 'true'),
      succeeded('Any_Tf_Changes_${{ parameters.environment }}') 
    )
  variables:
    anyTfChanges: $[ stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['anyTfChanges.anyTfChanges'] ]
    deps: $[convertToJson(dependencies)]
    stageDeps: $[convertToJson(stageDependencies)]
  jobs:
  - deployment: Apply
    environment: ${{ parameters.environmentDisplayName }}
    displayName: Apply Terraform
    # pool: 'selfhosted'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
          - powershell: |
              Write-Host "hello world"
              Write-Host "$(anyTfChanges)"
              Write-Host "deps is $(deps)"
              Write-Host "stageDeps is $(stageDeps)"




stage anyTfChanges variable error provided here.

at stage level reference, variable should be dependencies.STAGE.outputs['JOB.TASK.VARIABLE']
at job leve reference, variable should be stageDependencies.STAGE.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE']

your condition + variables must using the stage level variables variables: anyTfChanges: $[ dependencies.Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.outputs['Terraform_Plan_${{ parameters.environment }}.anyTfChanges.anyTfChanges'] ]
If not clear, just test my sample code, and you will find out everything.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: aStage
    jobs:
    - job: aJob
      steps:
        - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal;isOutput=true]yes"
          name: MyOutputVar

  - stage: bStage
    dependsOn: aStage
    jobs:
    - job: bJob
      variables:
        myStageAVar1: $[stageDependencies.aStage.aJob.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
      condition: eq(variables.myStageAVar1, 'yes')
      steps:
        - bash: echo $(myStageAVar1)
          name: print1

  - stage: cStage
    dependsOn: 
      - aStage
    variables:
      myStageAVar2: $[dependencies.aStage.outputs['aJob.MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
    condition: eq(variables.myStageAVar2, 'yes')
    jobs:
    - job: cJob
      steps:
        - bash: echo $(myStageAVar2)  ## this should show null
          name: print2

    - job: cJob2

      variables:
        myStageAVar3: $[stageDependencies.aStage.aJob.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
      steps:
        - bash: echo $(myStageAVar3) ## this should show yes
          name: print3

